# Web API modify incoming payload in formatter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, mediatypeformatter, message-handlers

All,

I am trying to modify the payload of incoming object via the web API. Currently I'm using a custom formatter which inherits from `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` and overrides the relevant methods.

Looks like this:

```
public override async Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    object obj =  await base.ReadFromStreamAsync(type, readStream, content, formatterLogger, cancellationToken);
    TrySetEventNo(obj, GetEventNo());
    return obj;
}

private void TrySetEventNo(object content, long eventNo)
{
    if (content is EventModelBase)
    {
        EventModelBase eventBase = (EventModelBase)content;
        eventBase.EventNo = eventNo;
    }
}
```

I'm using this to track every object that comes through the API.

Before all of this happens, I have a MessageHandler which is creating an event number and adding it to `Request.Properties`.

Trying to get the event number in the formatter which was created previously in the MessageHandler is proving difficult. Access `HttpContext.Current.Items["MS_HttpRequestMessage"].Properties` seems to be a different request as it does not contain the event number.

I've two questions:

1. Am I doing this the correctly or is there a better way?
2. If I am taking the correct approach, how to I get the correct Request to extract the event number?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, instead of attempting to do this inside a formatter I'm now using an `ActionFilterAttribute`.

overriding `OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)` and enumerating action `actionContext.ActionArguments`.

The complete solution looks like so:

```
public class SetModelEventNumberActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> actionArgument in actionContext.ActionArguments)
        {
            TrySetEventNo(actionArgument.Value, GetEventNo(actionContext));
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
    private void TrySetEventNo(object content, long eventNo)
    {
        if (content is EventPivotRequestMessageBase)
        {
            EventPivotRequestMessageBase eventBase = (EventPivotRequestMessageBase)content;
            eventBase.EventNo = eventNo;
        }
    }

    private long GetEventNo(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {

        long eventNo = (long)actionContext.Request.Properties[Constant.EVENT_ID];

        return eventNo;
    }
}
```